# Analysis on data recieved through POST request

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I want to make a basic rest API that takes a json file (converted from a dataframe) as a post request of the following format:

```
[{"supplier":1,"quantity":37},{"supplier":63,"quantity":32},{"supplier":1,"quantity":12}]
```

and performs some basic analysis on it, like lets say the average quantity for every supplier and send it back to the user.

I'm able to send the posted data back successfully as a json using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request
import pandas as pd


    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route("/basicAnalysis", methods=['POST'])
    def basicAnalysis():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                data = request.get_json(force=True)
                d=data.read_json(orient='records')
            except ValueError:
                return jsonify("something went wrong")

            return jsonify(d)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

But I do not know how to work with the recieved data. I've tried to convert the recieved 'data' to a dataframe so that I can work with it. But it isn't working out. Help will be appreciated.

**Edit 1:** Included the line I'm using to convert the json data to a dataframe. It gives me the following error:

```
builtins.AttributeError

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read_json'
```

I think the reason for this is that request.get_json() gives back a list item.

**Edit 2**: Added the libraries being imported in the code.

Comment: Can you show your *I've tried to convert the recieved 'data' to a dataframe* so someone can help you make that work?

Comment: Sorry for that, I've included the line.

Comment: Umm yeah.... `data`'s your previous variable that's a `list` so it won't have a `.read_json()` - how are you importing pandas? Have you got an `import pandas as pd` (traditional convention) somewhere?

Comment: Yes I'm using `import pandas as pd` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

If your flask code has successfully converted the received data to

```
data = [ {"supplier":1,"quantity":37},
         {"supplier":63,"quantity":32},
         {"supplier":1,"quantity":12} ]
```

then a pandas dataframe can be constructed with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If the data was still in json format, then

```
df = pd.read_json(data, orient='record')
```

should work